# How to get values from a textbox into gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

My requirement is that I need to develop a web page which has textboxes, labels and a submit button with gridview.

The thing is if I enter a value in textbox after giving submit button, it should save in gridview.

Gridview should have edit and delete button if we click on edit button the entire row should appear in respective textboxes and it should be able to edit and edited values should be saved in gridview again. And if we click on delete the entire row should get deleted.

Labels are

- firstname (validation should be thr)
- lastname
- city
- state (dropdown list box)
- zip (validation should be thr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know how to bind gridview after submitting values after filling textbox value ?

Look for following keywords,
1) Gridview.Datasource = datatable/dataset/resultset  
2) Gridview.databind() method.

Generate select query from db and store it in ant data value type. As shown above it will help you.

For gridView EDIT ,
you need to find use CommandText value , use DataKeyName as your row identical value. 
From that datakeyname you will get other details and display in textboxes.
Same For delete ....
Enjoy. IF not getting , we will provide you code.

Prefer [link](http://gurustop.net/blog/2008/01/25/gridview-databinding-events/)

Comment: Thanks Nikis just now i completed creating textboxes label and submit button and i got stuck up with after that as i am very new to asp.net

Comment: I need code fr above requirement so somebody help me.                                                                    Thanks

Comment: Please prefer that link

Comment: @IndhuElla  no matter of code , u can try it. 
is your problem solved ?

Comment: half way i am getting some error

Comment: which error u r getting

Comment: i got output for above requirement thanks for guiding :)

Comment: Yup..welcome. feel free to ask questions